# EditText shows then disappears under ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

Been stuck on this for hours trying to figure out why the EditText input box is not showing under my ListView. It first shows when I go to the screen but then disappears.

---

This is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fbd344"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="This Week Topic is: Registration Improvements"
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#0d701c"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message"
    android:id="@+id/chatlistview" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendBttn"
        android:hint="Say Something" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sendBttn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Send" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

---

I'm not sure what is causing this problem. If anyone has encountered this problem and can be of any help thank you.

Comment: what class are you extending your fragment with? `Fragment` or `ListFragment`?

Comment: I'm extending it with fragment.

Comment: try to remove the margin from ListView and align_parent_left, orientation from bottom Relative Layout.

Answer (score 0):

In ListView add the below code :

```
android:layout_above="@+id/form"
```

It will work.

Comment: That did not work. I still can not see the EditText when I have entered text in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `EditText` gets hidden under your `ListView` when the size of the size of the `ListView` increases.

Add the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chatlistview"
   >
```

Also don't forget to add the missing `</RelativeLayout>` tag.

Comment: No that did not work. The soft keyboard shows when I go to the activity, I enter the text, press enter, and then it disappears.

Comment: Check the edited answer. If this does not work then it might be something to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually showing when I tried using your layout code on my Android Studio. By the way in your code,

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

is missing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I actually have that, for some reason its not showing up in the the Question section. I can see the EditText fine in android studio, but when i run the app that's when I don't see it.

Comment: In your layout designer, when you click the device on the top, there is option to preview it on all devices. Try that and see if it is showing correctly on all device preview. Hope that helps.